# Why Scrapy.response.follow() scrapes list of links randomly in iteration? Because of Recursion? How to resolve?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I scraped titles of the courses from Datacamp But it print titles randomly.
I have created a simple spider that **scrape** titles of the courses on datacamp.com.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
```

This is the Class that is actual spider:

```
class DataOfDatacamp(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "DataOfDatacamp"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://www.datacamp.com/courses/all?embedded=true", callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.css('a.course-block__link::attr(href)').extract()
        print(links)
        for link in links:
            yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse2)

    def parse2(self, response):
        print(response.css("h1.header-hero__title::text").extract_first())
```

Here he spider is launched:

```
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(DataOfDatacamp)
process.start()
```

Comment: Did you try the script below @Talha Irfan?

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to get them all consistently. Turn out that the class responsible to fetch the title are different in several containers, as in `header-hero__title`, `dc-course__header-title` e.t.c. Luckily there is a portion of class which is common in all of them which is `title`, so I made use of that. Bringing about the change fetches them all.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class DataOfDatacamp(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "DataOfDatacamp"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://www.datacamp.com/courses/all?embedded=true", callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('a.course-block__link::attr(href)').getall():
            yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse2)

    def parse2(self, response):
        print(response.css("h1[class*='title']::text").get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess({'LOG_LEVEL':'ERROR'})
    process.crawl(DataOfDatacamp)
    process.start()
```